# How to make merge or intercalate two maps in scala one by one?

Tags: scala, merge, maps

I want to merge two maps in a list of maps as follow:

```
val map1 = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3}
val map2 = {"x" -> 10, "y" -> 20, "z" -> 30}

val res = [{"a" ->1, "x" -> 10},{"b" -> 2, "y" -> 20},{"c" -> 3, "z" -> 30}]
```

Comment: In another example I try something like this and it seems to work.
val j = List(Map(("string", 1),("string",2),("string",3)))
      
val s = j.map(l => ("amount", l)) zip j.map(l => ("items", l))
      val m = s.map(x=> List(x._1) ++ List(x._2))
      val n = m.map(x => x.toMap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
val map1 = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)
val map2 = Map("x" -> 10, "y" -> 20, "z" -> 30)


(map1.toList, map2.toList).zipped.map{
   case (a,b) => Map(a,b)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
val map1 = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)
val map2 = Map("x" -> 10, "y" -> 20, "z" -> 30)

val res = for ((i, j) <- map1 zip map2) yield Map(i, j)
```